# Angular - change header components by current lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

I need to change the components in the header by the current lazy load module.

For example in the below image, change the components when the current route/module changing.
but without moving the component to another module (they should stay in the lazy module).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsuyu.jpg)

what is the best way to do it?
Thanks,
Liad

Comment: can you please provide more information ? I could not understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Welcome @liad microsoft on StackOverflow, It would be really helpful for others to understand your question if you attached your code which causes the problem. For more help please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask